# Why do I get fewer miles on MNL-IST-GRU vs MNL-IST on Turkish Airlines?

Tags: loyalty-programs, turkish-airlines

If I book Manila to São Paulo (with a stopover in Istanbul) on Turkish Airlines I only earn 1,250 miles in my account.

But if I book Manila to Istanbul, it's 7,082 miles. Why does the shorter flight earn more points?

Comment: Did you already travel and earn those miles, or did you just check prices and miles on the Turkish Airlines website? If you already travelled, what fare class is each of the legs (this should be visible on your e-ticket or boarding passes, sometimes on the miles statement), and did you get the miles for all the flights already? If you haven't traveled yet, what are the dates and the fare classes (it shows up next to the flight number, e.g. "Economy Promotion (L)"? The minimum number of miles (one way) should be 3058 miles.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the fare classes on the tickets. See the following links.

Wikipedia: [Fare basis code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fare_basis_code).

Turkish Airlines: [Counting miles based on fare class](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-ee/miles-and-smiles/program-partners/airlines/turkish-airlines/index.html).

PS: [Interesting video explaining fare classes pricing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72hlr-E7KA0).

Comment: Generally, that means that cheaper tickets get less miles for the same route (though this is not an absolute rule, as fares of various fare classes may overlap).

Comment: Nevertheless, there's something wrong here... MNL-IST-GRU is 12232 miles. Even the cheapest ticket (W,P,F,U) would get 25% = 3058 miles.

Comment: @jcaron As I don't have enough reputation can you comment on the question to ask for more information?

Comment: I had class V ticket which means I should still get 50% but only end up getting roughly 3000 miles. Their mileage calculator seems to be wrong because it shows 1250 for all class (MNL-GRU)

Comment: @mightymau Did you get the miles for all flights? On a class V ticket you should get 2842 miles for MNL-IST and 3273 for IST-GRU (for a ticket bought from TK on a flight with a TK flight number operated by TK, rules may be very different in other circumstances).

Comment: @jcaron Yes I got the miles for all flights, here is a copy of my miles statement: 
MNL - IST Y Flight - 1417
IST - GRU Y Flight - 1644
Im not sure what Y is because my reservation was class V.
Im planning to travel again the same route just want to make sure I get the right miles this time.

Comment: @mightymau Y can mean either full-fare economy, or any economy fare, depending on context (probably the latter here). It looks like the mileage accrual table of TK changed recently. [V used to earn 25%](https://web.archive.org/web/20180321155451/https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/miles-and-smiles/program-partners/airlines/turkish-airlines/index.html). Don't know when the new chart took effect.

Comment: @mightymau also, where did the 1250 miles in your question come from?

Comment: @jcaron ahh I guess I got the 25% accrual rate before. I'm planning to go to BraziI again so I checked their Mileage Calculator and it shows 1250 miles for MNL-GRU for all fare classes. I think there's something wrong with their website.

Comment: @mightymau I recommend you check the miles shown on the booking pages. They're shown on the page after the flight selection, and will reflect the actual booking class selected for that flight.

Comment: sorry I did not mean to say "for all fare classes" their mileage calculator shows MNL-GRU (Economy: Y,B) 1,250

Comment: @mightymau that's the minimum amount of miles you would get for an Y fare, even if the flight was less than 1000 miles. Looks like a bug in the calculator. In any case, miles are awarded by segment (flight), so check MNL-IST and IST-GRU separately. But the booking engine pages will give the right information in any case.